# Standby mode for nodes depending on topic value

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, spinonce, spin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's assume we have 10 nodes performing various operations. We run all the nodes with one launch file at a time. We also have one topic "/mode" in which we specify the value of int. Now we want certain nodes to execute depending on the value of "/mode". Is there any better way to do this in the ROS environment than subscribe the "/mode" topic, check the value, and if it is incorrect, we just do return in callbacks? Can I freeze the nodes somehow depending on topic value? I mean, nodes should be in standby mode and wait for specific output of "/mode" topic and run callbacks until "/mode" is correct. I want to run and stop node several times through topic value.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360115/standby-mode-for-nodes-depending-on-topic-value/) by [definitive](https://answers.ros.org/users/57454/definitive/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2020-08-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure about how much use it sees, but for ROS 1, perhaps [boschresearch/ros1_lifecycle](https://github.com/boschresearch/ros1_lifecycle) could be an option.

It's essentially a/the ROS 2 lifecycle, but for ROS 1.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS1, I think what you've proposed is the best possible solution available.

If you were to move to ROS2 in the future, check out [Managed Nodes](https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html) which implement a lifecycle, so you could have a central node that starts and stops the desired nodes at different times.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2020-08-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1